# Firefox extension: even listener to changes inside a panel

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I would like some assistance with this:

- Firefox extension opens a panel, loads content from external website
- How do I listen to changes inside the panel's content? It's dynamic and constantly updated
- When changes happen, fire a notification inside the browser (something like "There are some news!")

Here is a bit of code (sorry but I'm quite the noob):

```
var Widget = require("widget").Widget;

var tabs = require('tabs');

exports.main = function() {

      data = require("self").data

        var Panel = require("panel").Panel({
              width:1000,
              height:630,
              contentURL: "http://mysite.com/news.html",
        });

        require("widget").Widget({
              id: "News",
              label: "News",
              contentURL: "http://mysite.com/images/favicon.ico",
              panel: Panel

            });

        };
```

Comment: Why not have a think and ask a specific question?

Comment: Sorry! I've just edited my question

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to inject some contentScript into the page ( http://mysite.com/news.html ) and watch for changes via that script.  When you see the change you want just send a message up to the panel to notify the add-on of that change.

I'll annotate the example from the docs,

```
// this could be listening to any event happening in the page
var myScript = "window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {" +
               "  var t = event.target;" +
               "  if (t.nodeName == 'A')" +
                    //  this self.port.emit is what sends the 'click-link' signal
                    //  to your add-on code
               "    self.port.emit('click-link', t.toString());" +
               "}, false);"

var panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  contentURL: "http://mysite.com/news.html",
  // !!! use contentScriptFile, this is just for small inline stuff
  contentScript: myScript
});

// this is how your add-on listens for the 'click-link' signal, but it could be any signal name you want
panel.port.on("click-link", function(url) {
  // here is where you fire the "There are some news!" event in the browser
  console.log(url);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'd give you rep but I can't vote I'm too green in this community :)